# What's the difference between . and # in a css file?

Tags: css, syntax

In css examples, I've seen rules defined starting with a `.` and some starting with `#` - sometimes these are mixed in the same file.  What is the difference between these rules:

```
h1  { font-size:18pt;}
.new-alerts  { font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;}
#old-alerts  { position:relative; font-size:10pt; }
```

Are they referenced differently on the html page?  Is it how the properties are inherited?

Comment: Belongs here: http://doctype.com/

Comment: I'm not sure it does. Doctype seems to be more about design, whereas this is about the semantics of the language itself.

Comment: @Jon: Not necessarily ... *»If your question is about web design and HTML/CSS layout, **and your job title is "designer",** ask on Doctype.«* – I don't think it's wrong here.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`.` refers to a class. `<span class="one" />` could be selected with `.one`.

`#` refers to an ID. `<span id="one" />` could be selected with `#one`.

You should be using classes when there could be more than one of a given element, and IDs when you know there will only be one. `#navigation-bar` would be using an ID because you will only have one navigation bar in your layout, but `.navigation-link` would be using a class name because you will have multiple navigation links. (It'd be better practice to use `#navigation-bar a:link` to get the navigation links, but you get my point.)

Comment: What does that mean? How are they different?

Comment: They're both ways to semantically add information to an element. While you can only mark one element with a particular `id`, you can have many with the same `class`.

Comment: You use ID's for one specific tag, it's unique and you should only have one of the same ID on a page.  Classes are re-usable and can be applied to as many elements as you want.

Comment: First added basic answer, then went back to add explanation.

Comment: However, `.navigation-link` might also be replaced by `#navigation-bar a:link` which refers to a link within the navigation bar. Note that elements itself have semantic meaning most of the time and you can save yourself the use of too many classes if you use them properly.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Note added :)

Comment: Another consideration to make when deciding whether to use a class or an id is that with ids you can direct users directly to the content by putting the id in the URL, aka an "anchor". http://www.example.com/index.html#about_us would go to that id in the content of the page.

Answer (score 10):

The dot `.` is a [*class selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html), the hash/pound/octothorpe `#` [selects by an ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors):

```
<style>
    .foo { ... }
    #bar { ... }
</style>
...
<p class='foo'>Foo</p>
<p id='bar' class='baz'>Bar</p>
```

IDs have to be unique throughout a document, classes don't have to be. That's basically the primary difference. There are some things to note with regard to scripting but those are usually not of particular interest when styling.

Furthermore, an element may belong to multiple classes:

```
<p class="foo bar baz">
```

and as seen above, classes and IDs are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

. is a class and can be reused many times and for different elements

# is an ID and must be used only once on each page.

Answer (score 1):

[See Class vs ID](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php)